# How to use webpack-hot-middleware with multiple entry object

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, webpack-hot-middleware

My entry point in webpack looks like this.

```
module.exports = {
mode: 'development',
entry: {
    app: './src/legacy-base/garbage.js',
    admin_panel: {
        import: './src/admin-panel-react/index.jsx',
        filename: './partner-portal/admin-panel-bundle.js',
    }
},
```

How I can use here webpack-hot-middleware here, because all examples go with arrays. If entry is object, there is only example like this

```
entry: {
  vendor: ['jquery', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client'],
  index: ['./src/index', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client']
}
```

But I can't use it in my case, because for admin-panel I need to use import and filename keys. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @fabrizzio_gz, unfortunately no. Seems need to be rewritten to array style